Finding References for known results about mixing time of a Markov chain arising from Gaussian elimination
I am looking for references for the known results on the following problem. Let $(X_t)$ be a Markov chain on $GL_n(F_2)$, where in each step, an ordered pair $(i,j)$ is chosen uniformly at random, and   row i  is added to row j mod 2. According to the website of mathematician Yuval Peres (https://www.yp-open-problems.com/a-markov-chain-arising-from-gaussian-elimination/) the known lower bound is of order $n^2/(\log n)$. I couldn't find any reference for it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

There are at least $N=c2^{n^2}$ invertible matrices mod 2, where $c=1/2(1-1/4)(1-1/8)\cdots (1-2^{-k})\cdots>0$.
Since there are less than $n^2$ possible moves in each step, after $t$ steps the distribution $P^t(I, \cdot)$ is supported on at most $n^{2t}$ matrices.
If $t<an^2/logn$ for a small constant $a$, then $n^{2t}$ is much smaller than $N$, which implies the total variation distance between $P^t(I, \cdot)$ and the uniform distribution on $GL_n(F_2)$ is close to 1.
You can also check that the diameter of $GL_n(F_2)$ in the relevant graph is at least $an^2/\log(n)$, and use the diameter lower bound on mixing time.
In [1] there is an upper bound of order $O(n^3)$ for the mixing time; some projections and variants of this chain are analyzed in [2], [3].
References
[1] M. Kassabov. Kazhdan constants for SLn(Z). International Journal of Algebra and Computation, 15(05n06):971–995, 2005. MR-21978
[2] Ben-Hamou, Anna, and Yuval Peres. "Cutoff for a stratified random walk on the hypercube." (2018): 1-10.
[3] Peres, Y., Tanaka, R. and Zhai, A., 2020. Cutoff for product replacement on finite groups. Probability Theory and Related Fields, 177(3), pp.823-853.
